# taking percentile on different ids in the dataframe with numpy.percentile

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have to take the percentile on the whole data at once but I have several ids data and want to have the separate results of all ids. here is my code where i am getting some error

```
result_frame.groupby('ID').apply(percentile('rolling_mean', [25]))
```

I am getting the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-87a94290cfde> in <module>()
----> 1 result_frame.groupby('VoyageID').apply(percentile('rolling_mean', [25]))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in percentile(a, q, axis, out, overwrite_input, interpolation, keepdims)
   4272     r, k = _ureduce(a, func=_percentile, q=q, axis=axis, out=out,
   4273                     overwrite_input=overwrite_input,
-> 4274                     interpolation=interpolation)
   4275     if keepdims:
   4276         if q.ndim == 0:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _ureduce(a, func, **kwargs)
   4014         keepdim = [1] * a.ndim
   4015 
-> 4016     r = func(a, **kwargs)
   4017     return r, keepdim
   4018 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _percentile(a, q, axis, out, overwrite_input, interpolation, keepdims)
   4389             n = np.isnan(ap[-1:, ...])
   4390 
-> 4391         x1 = take(ap, indices_below, axis=axis) * weights_below
   4392         x2 = take(ap, indices_above, axis=axis) * weights_above
   4393 

TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['A', 'B'] * 100, 'value': np.random.randn(200)})

data.groupby('group')['value'].quantile([.25, .75])
```

You are correct to group, you just need to identify the column you'd like to summarise, and then apply the percentile using [quantile](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html).